# List of docker containers in repository

Tags: docker

I have installed Docker containers according [manual](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#upgrade-docker-ce)

Command below adds repository with ubuntu containers:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

Whole container list:

```
apt-cache madison docker-ce

 docker-ce | 17.12.1~ce-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 17.12.0~ce-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 17.09.1~ce-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 17.09.0~ce-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 17.06.2~ce-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 17.06.1~ce-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 17.06.0~ce-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 17.03.2~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 17.03.1~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 17.03.0~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial/stable amd64 Packages
```

To test system container `hello-world` was used

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

But where `hello-world` came from? I don't see it on the list? How to know list of other 'hidden' containers?

Answer (score 1):

When you run the below command, docker will search your local machine for the hello-world image. Since you don't have one, it will fetch it from dockerhub and run it.

`$ sudo docker run hello-world`

After running the hello world container. if you run the below command, it will list the docker images available in your local machine

```
$ docker images
```

Comment: `apt-cache madison docker-ce` not shows hello-world in the list. Where it came from?

Comment: apt-cache madison docker-ce displays the available docker community version available that you can install in your system. Not the images that you download and run

Only docker images command lists you the images available in your local machine.

If you need to search for docker images in docker hub, use {docker search [OPTIONS] TERM}

refer --> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/search/

Comment: When you run the docker run command, it will get the images from docker hub registry, download it and run it in your machine.

Comment: ok, and what does `docker-ce` means. Is it some special set of images?

Comment: ce means community edition.
When you say apt-cache, it lists the available repositories for docker community edition for your system.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [docker images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#description) command to see the list of images present locally:

```
$ docker images

REPOSITORY        TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
redis             latest              33c26d72bd74        4 weeks ago         107MB
hello-world       latest              f2a91732366c        3 months ago        1.85kB
```

The command `apt-cache madison docker-ce` lists the available ubuntu packages for all the different version of the docker binary and tools.

Comment: but how `docker-ce` is related only to `Ubuntu` packages. How to list all `Centos` packages?

Comment: `apt-cache madison docker-ce` not shows hello-world in the list. Where it came from?